# Naive method to find a pair in a list with the given sum

Tags: python

two integer pair values and will have a target value. Now you have to find the index of two pair values by target value

```py
def findPair(nums, target):
 
    # consider each element except the last
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
 
        # start from the i'th element until the last element
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
 
            # if the desired sum is found, print it
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                print('Pair found', (nums[i], nums[j]))
                return
 
    # No pair with the given sum exists in the list
    print('Pair not found')
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    nums = [[1, 5],[9, -7],[0, 8],[6, 3],[4, 11],[14, 0],[8, 1],[4, 9],]

    target = 9
 
    findPair(nums, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findPair(nums, target):
 
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        # if the desired sum is found, print it
        if nums[i][0] + nums[i][1] == target:
            print('Pair found', (nums[i][0], nums[i][1]))
            return
 
    # No pair with the given sum exists in the list
    print('Pair not found')
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    nums = [[1, 5],[9, -7],[0, 8],[6, 3],[4, 11],[14, 0],[8, 1],[4, 9],]

    target = 9
 
    findPair(nums, target)
```

Simply add the first and second element of each 2d element.